# Same question as one asked a few days ago: why is this puppeteer code not working on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, try-catch, puppeteer

I think this is an issue that just popped up with Heroku and Puppeteer because someone asked the same exact thing a few days ago:

https://ittone.ma/ittone/javascript-puppeteer-works-locally-but-not-when-pushed-to-heroku/

I have the same exact error here, which leads me to believe it's something with the setup of the scraper browser or something. Mine looks like:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const puppeteerExtra = require('puppeteer-extra');
const pluginStealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');

process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r));

const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {

    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +           
      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {
        get: () => false,
      });
    });

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      const originalQuery = window.navigator.permissions.query;
      return window.navigator.permissions.query = (parameters) => (
        parameters.name === 'notifications' ?
          Promise.resolve({ state: Notification.permission }) :
          originalQuery(parameters)
      );
    });

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
      Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'plugins', {
        // This just needs to have `length > 0` for the current test,
        // but we could mock the plugins too if necessary.
        get: () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      });
    });

    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(() => {
      // Overwrite the `plugins` property to use a custom getter.
      Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'languages', {
        get: () => ['en-US', 'en'],
      });
    });
  }

  puppeteerExtra.use(pluginStealth());
  const browser = await puppeteerExtra.launch({ args: [                
  '--no-sandbox'                                                  
  ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await preparePageForTests(page);
  await page.goto(`link`);   
  const resultList = await page.waitForSelector("classID");
  const scrollableSection = await page.waitForSelector("pathToSelector");

  const results = await page.$$("classID");
```

I have the same exact errors that the person in the link had but they deleted their post for some reason...anyone who helped answer that question or linked the author to the correct answer, please help me as well--thank you!

Errors Returned:

```
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590327+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590336+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590336+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590337+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590337+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: read ENOTCONN
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590338+00:00 app[web.1]: at tryReadStart (net.js:574:20)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590338+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket._read (net.js:585:5)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590339+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.Readable.read (internal/streams/readable.js:481:10)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590339+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.read (net.js:625:39)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590340+00:00 app[web.1]: at new Socket (net.js:377:12)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590340+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Socket (net.js:269:41)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590341+00:00 app[web.1]: at createSocket (internal/child_process.js:314:14)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590341+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:433:23)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590341+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.spawn (child_process.js:553:9)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590342+00:00 app[web.1]: at BrowserRunner.start (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:80:34)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590343+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590343+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590343+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590344+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590344+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -107,
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590344+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ENOTCONN',
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590345+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'read'
2021-05-11T21:03:24.590345+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-05-11T21:03:24.782503+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-05-11T21:03:24.783383+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-05-11T21:03:24.822534+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! server@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2021-05-11T21:03:24.824335+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-05-11T21:03:24.824783+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-05-11T21:03:24.825073+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the server@1.0.0 start script.
2021-05-11T21:03:24.826085+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-05-11T21:03:24.869275+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T21:03:24.869729+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-05-11T21:03:24.870013+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-05-11T21_03_24_830Z-debug.log
```

Errors Returned w/ process.on('unhandledRejection') addition (Stack Trace?):

```
2021-05-11T23:58:07.628276+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-11T23:58:07.628278+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-05-11T23:58:07.628400+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-11T23:58:07.628494+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.
11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-11T23:58:07.628580+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295178+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295187+00:00 app[web.1]: [0511/235810.186514:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(135)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295187+00:00 app[web.1]: [0511/235810.186668:FATAL:thread_pool_impl.cc(176)] Check failed: service_thread_.StartWithOptions(service_thread_options).
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295188+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x556365222259 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295188+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x55636518e9e3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295189+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x55636519f610 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295189+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x5563651a00ce logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295190+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x5563651fc16c base::internal::ThreadPoolImpl::Start()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295190+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x5563637da398 content::StartBrowserThreadPool()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295191+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x55636512edbf content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295191+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x55636512ec5d content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295192+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x55636512c29d content::RunContentProcess()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295192+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x55636512cc3d content::ContentMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295192+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x556365188c29 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295193+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x55636518893a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295194+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x5563621b93e1 ChromeMain
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295194+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x7fb7362dc0b3 __libc_start_main
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295195+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x5563621b922a _start
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295195+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295195+00:00 app[web.1]: Received signal 6
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295196+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x556365222259 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295196+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x55636518e9e3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295197+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x556365221e00 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295197+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x7fb737c66420 (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.31.so+0x1541f)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295197+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x7fb7362fb18b gsignal
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295198+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x7fb7362da859 abort
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295198+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x556365221425 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295199+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x55636519fa37 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295199+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x5563651a00ce logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295199+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x5563651fc16c base::internal::ThreadPoolImpl::Start()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295199+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x5563637da398 content::StartBrowserThreadPool()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295200+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x55636512edbf content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295200+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x55636512ec5d content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295200+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x55636512c29d content::RunContentProcess()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295201+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x55636512cc3d content::ContentMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295201+00:00 app[web.1]: #15 0x556365188c29 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295201+00:00 app[web.1]: #16 0x55636518893a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295201+00:00 app[web.1]: #17 0x5563621b93e1 ChromeMain
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295202+00:00 app[web.1]: #18 0x7fb7362dc0b3 __libc_start_main
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295202+00:00 app[web.1]: #19 0x5563621b922a _start
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295203+00:00 app[web.1]: r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffd77c6f2e0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295203+00:00 app[web.1]: r12: 0000258000304000 r13: 00007ffd77c6f540 r14: 0000258000304010 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295203+00:00 app[web.1]: di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffd77c6f2e0  bp: 00007ffd77c6f530  bx: 00007fb734f3cdc0
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295204+00:00 app[web.1]: dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: 00007fb7362fb18b  sp: 00007ffd77c6f2e0
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295204+00:00 app[web.1]: ip: 00007fb7362fb18b efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295204+00:00 app[web.1]: trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295205+00:00 app[web.1]: [end of stack trace]
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295205+00:00 app[web.1]: Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295205+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295206+00:00 app[web.1]: TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295206+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295206+00:00 app[web.1]: at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:194:20)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Interface.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:184:68)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Interface.emit (events.js:327:22)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295207+00:00 app[web.1]: at Interface.close (readline.js:424:8)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295208+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.onend (readline.js:202:10)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295208+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:327:22)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295208+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1327:12)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.295209+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354377+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354379+00:00 app[web.1]: [0511/235810.204102:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(135)] pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable (11)
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354388+00:00 app[web.1]: [0511/235810.204262:FATAL:thread_pool_impl.cc(176)] Check failed: service_thread_.StartWithOptions(service_thread_options).
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354389+00:00 app[web.1]: #0 0x559e0b1f9259 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354389+00:00 app[web.1]: #1 0x559e0b1659e3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354390+00:00 app[web.1]: #2 0x559e0b176610 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354390+00:00 app[web.1]: #3 0x559e0b1770ce logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354390+00:00 app[web.1]: #4 0x559e0b1d316c base::internal::ThreadPoolImpl::Start()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354391+00:00 app[web.1]: #5 0x559e097b1398 

content::StartBrowserThreadPool()
    2021-05-11T23:58:11.354392+00:00 app[web.1]: #6 0x559e0b105dbf content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunBrowser()
    2021-05-11T23:58:11.354392+00:00 app[web.1]: #7 0x559e0b105c5d 
content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()

2021-05-11T23:58:11.354393+00:00 app[web.1]: #8 0x559e0b10329d content::RunContentProcess()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354393+00:00 app[web.1]: #9 0x559e0b103c3d content::ContentMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354393+00:00 app[web.1]: #10 0x559e0b15fc29 headless::HeadlessBrowserMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354394+00:00 app[web.1]: #11 0x559e0b15f93a headless::HeadlessShellMain()
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354394+00:00 app[web.1]: #12 0x559e081903e1 ChromeMain
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354395+00:00 app[web.1]: #13 0x7f3f03d720b3 __libc_start_main
2021-05-11T23:58:11.354395+00:00 app[web.1]: #14 0x559e0819022a _start
```

Heroku Config Vars:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eL4Cf.png

Comment: If it helps, I'm scraping google concerts.

Comment: Add the error message pls and the config of heroku

Comment: @JuanRambal Done, thanks. Also not sure what I did to deserve the instant downvote, seeing as I'm just asking a question that is no longer anywhere in the community, but I guess someone saw the "Same question" in the title and downvoted...

Comment: Try launching the browser in headless mode { headless: true }

Comment: I did what you suggested. The default is headless but I made the opening mode explicitly headless. I also changed the buildpack to have a .git appended to the end. I also added process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r)); to my code and put in the error logs that were returned from that.  Essentially, what my function does is it runs scraping whenever the user taps a button. (This is why there are many returns, I think). If you'd like to move this to chat or hop on a discord call I can also do that, as it might be easier to figure out a solution @JuanRambal

Answer (score 2):

Because:

> Puppeteer defaults to headless: true in puppeteer.launch and this
> shouldn't be changed. Heroku doesn't have a GUI to show you chrome
> when running headless: false and Heroku will throw an error.

Check out:
https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack

To solve:

1. Loginto heroku dahsboard
2. Go to your app
3. Click settings
4. Click add buildpack
5. paste: https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack.git
6. Redeploy

Comment: I did what you suggested. The default is headless but I made the opening mode explicitly headless. I also changed the buildpack to have a .git appended to the end. I also added process.on('unhandledRejection', r => console.log(r)); to my code and put in the error logs that were returned from that. Essentially, what my function does is it runs scraping whenever the user taps a button. (This is why there are many returns, I think). If you'd like to move this to chat or hop on a discord call I can also do that, as it might be easier to figure out a solution